# Should my bucket be public for my usecase and how should I avoid bad practice?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I'm new to AWS tools and although I have tried to search thoroughly for an answer I wasn't able to fixate on a solution.

My usecase is this:
I have a bucket where I need to store images, upload them via my server however I need to display them on my website.

Should my bucket be public?
If not, what should I do to allow everyone to read those images but not be able to mass upload on it from origins who are not my server?

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to respond!
at the moment I haven't deployed my server just yet however I did end up setting up my bucket private and using cloudfront to access the public images!
will update soon once i deploy my server @Marcin

Answer (score 2):

If you want the images to be publicly accessible for your website, then the objects need to be public.

This can be done by creating a **Bucket Policy** that makes the whole bucket, or part of the bucket, publicly accessible.

Alternatively, when uploading the images, you can use `ACL='public-read'`, which makes the individual objects public even if the bucket isn't public. This way, you can have more fine-grained control over what content in the bucket is public.

Both of these options require you to turn off portions of **S3 Block Public Access** to allow the Bucket Policy or ACLs.

When your server uploads to S3, it should be using Amazon S3 API calls using a set of **AWS credentials (Access Key, Secret Key) from an IAM User**. Grant the IAM User permission to put objects in the bucket. This way, that software can upload to the bucket totally independently to whether the bucket is public. (Never make a bucket publicly writable/uploadable, otherwise people can store anything in there without your control.)

Answer (score 0):

> upload them via my server however I need to display them on my website.

In that case only your server can upload the images. So if you are hosting your web app on EC2 or ECS, then you use [instance role](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/iam-roles-for-amazon-ec2.html) and [task role](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/task-iam-roles.html) to provide S3 write access.

> Should my bucket be public?

It does not have to. Often [CloudFront is used to host images or files from S3 using OAI](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/networking-and-content-delivery/amazon-s3-amazon-cloudfront-a-match-made-in-the-cloud/). This way your bucket remains fully private.